# How to find the limit of $\sqrt{n}\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}e^{1-\frac{1}{i}}\left(1+\frac{1}{i}\right)^{-i}$

Tags: limits

Find the limits
$$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{e^{1-\frac{1}{i}}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{i}\right)^i}=0?$$

My idea:
Note
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{i}\right)^i=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{(i+1)^{i+1}}{i^i\cdot(i+1)}=\dfrac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$
and
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}e^{1-\dfrac{1}{i}}=e^{n-H_{n}}$$
so
$$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{n}(n+1)!e^{n-H_{n}}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$$
use this 
$$n!\approx (n/e)^n\cdot\sqrt{2n\pi}$$
so
$$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{n+1}{e}\right)^{n+1}\sqrt{2(n+1)\pi}e^{n-H_{n}}\sqrt{n}}
{(n+1)^{n+1}}$$
so
$$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e}\dfrac{n+1}{e^{H_{n}}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e}e^{-c}$$
where is wrong?so I can't have this limts is $0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that
$$n!\approx (n/e)^n\cdot\sqrt{2\pi n}\ \Rightarrow \ \frac{n!}{n^n}\approx e^{-n} \sqrt{2\pi n}$$
Therefore
$$I = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n}e^{n-H_{n}}\cdot \dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n}e^{n-H_{n}} \cdot e^{-(n+1)} \sqrt{2\pi (n+1)}$$
Simplifying
$$I = e^{-1}\sqrt{2\pi} \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-H_n}\sqrt{n^2+n}$$

Now use that $H_n = \log n + \gamma + \epsilon_n$ ($\epsilon_n \to 0$ as $n \to\infty$) to conclude:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-H_n}\sqrt{n^2+n} =\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-\log n}e^{-\gamma}e^{-\epsilon_n}\sqrt{n^2+n}=e^{-\gamma}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}}{n} = e^{-\gamma}$$
Thus, we find

> $$I = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e^{1+\gamma}}$$